# How to make different style numbered list and bulleted list in content editable div by jQuery HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I am creating a rich text editor without any plugin because I can not customize any plugin with my own style.

Now I want to add several style bullet list and numbered list.

Numbered style like below:

```
1) adsdd
    a)sdsdsds
        i)dfdfdfddf
2)erererere
```

Bullet style will be like below:

```
*aaaa
    - bbbbbb
+ cccccc
```

I want to use different symbols when press tab key. Also when press tab key in content editable div it will forward for four space.

I used execcomand for orderlist and unorderlist but it gives me only one style. But i want different style and one list have under child list when press tabkey, the child list also have another child list again when press tabkey.

My jQuery code is there:

```javascript
function orderList1() {
    document.execCommand('formatblock', false, 'p')
    var listId = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
    $(listId).addClass("oder2");
    alert(listId);
    $(".textcontent").keydown(function(e) {
        if(i<6){
            if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                if(i===0){
                    var listId1 = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
                    $(listId1).removeClass('oder2');
                    $(listId1).addClass("oder3");
                    i++;
                    $(".textcontent").keydown(function(e) {
                        if(e.keyCode == 8){
                            var nodeNull = listId1.textContent;
                            if(listId1.textContent === '')
                                alert(nodeNull);
                            $(listId1).removeClass('oder3');

                        }
                    });

                }
                else if(i===1){
                    var listId2 = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
                    $(listId2).removeClass("oder3");
                    $(listId2).addClass("oder4");
                    i++;
                }
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
//                        return false;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}
.oder2{
    counter-reset: subsection;
    padding-left: 3em;
}
.oder2:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content:  counter(section) ") ";
}
.oder3 {
    counter-reset: subsection1;
    padding-left: 6em;
}
.oder3:before {
    counter-increment: subsection;
    content: counter(subsection, lower-alpha) ") " ;
/*counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";*/
}
.oder4{
    padding-left: 9em;
}
.oder4:before {
    counter-increment: subsection1;
    content: counter(subsection1, lower-roman) ") " ;
/*counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";*/
}
```

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: I think it also create by only PHP condition. I used PHP codeigniter framework for this.